# Error After deleting rows in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have frame which contains a table and two buttons.

[image]

1) Duplicate Row
2) Delete Row

the table a combo in third column

I have a scenario where i duplicate the blank rows and click on the last row's combo box to select that row and then click on Delete Row Button... then after deleting the whenever i try to click any cell it gives me the following error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6 >= 6
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.stopCellEditing(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$3.stopCellEditing(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.stopCellEditing(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the source code for the frame in question.

```
public class UI {

    JFrame frame;
    JTable TblFilePane1;

    UI()
    {
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension screen = kit.getScreenSize();

        frame = new JFrame("Web Automation Tool (Selenium)");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocation(screen.width/5, screen.height/300);       
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 820));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        final JPanel Pane1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        final JPanel FotterPanelPane1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());


        String columnNamesTestSuitePane1[] = { "Scope ID","Test Suite","Data File Required","Data File Path"};
        // Create some data
        String dataValuesTestSuitePane1[][] =
        {
            { "","","Yes","" },
        };      


        // Create a new table instance
        TblFilePane1 = new JTable( dataValuesTestSuitePane1, columnNamesTestSuitePane1 );
        TblFilePane1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        TblFilePane1.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        TblFilePane1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        DefaultTableModel modelPane1 = new DefaultTableModel(dataValuesTestSuitePane1, columnNamesTestSuitePane1);

        TblFilePane1.setModel(modelPane1);
        TblFilePane1.setRowHeight(22);
        final JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane( TblFilePane1 );
        //scrollPane1.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 250);

        //final LineNumberTableRowHeader TblFilePane1LineNumber = new LineNumberTableRowHeader(scrollPane1, TblFilePane1);
        //TblFilePane1LineNumber.setBackground(Color.orange);
        //scrollPane1.setRowHeaderView(TblFilePane1LineNumber);


        TableColumn ScopeIDPane1 = TblFilePane1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);          
        ScopeIDPane1.setPreferredWidth(30);

        TableColumn TSIDPane1 = TblFilePane1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);         
        ScopeIDPane1.setPreferredWidth(30);

        TableColumn dfReq = TblFilePane1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        JComboBox cmbDfReq = new JComboBox();
        cmbDfReq.addItem("Yes");
        cmbDfReq.addItem("No"); 
        dfReq.setPreferredWidth(40);

        TableColumn DataFile = TblFilePane1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);          
        DataFile.setPreferredWidth(490);

        TableColumn NotEditable = TblFilePane1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        JTextField ScopeIDNE = new JTextField();
        ScopeIDNE.setEnabled(false);


        TableColumn NotEditableTS = TblFilePane1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        JTextField TSIDNE = new JTextField();
        TSIDNE.setEnabled(false);

        NotEditableTS.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(TSIDNE));
        NotEditable.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(ScopeIDNE));
        dfReq.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(cmbDfReq));

        Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 5, 10);
        FotterPanelPane1.setBorder(margin);

        FotterPanelPane1.add(scrollPane1,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final JPanel BtnPanelPane1 = new JPanel();
        JButton BtnDuplicateRow = new JButton("Duplicate Row");
        JButton BtnDeleteRowPane1 = new JButton("Delete Row");
        BtnPanelPane1.add(BtnDuplicateRow);
        BtnPanelPane1.add(BtnDeleteRowPane1);

        Pane1.add(FotterPanelPane1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Pane1.add(BtnPanelPane1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(Pane1);

        frame.pack();

        BtnDuplicateRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel)TblFilePane1.getModel();
                int totalRows = TblFilePane1.getRowCount();

                Vector data = model.getDataVector();

                int[] rows = TblFilePane1.getSelectedRows();
                 if(rows.length != 1)
                 {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Select one row to Duplicate !");
                 }

                 else
                 {
                     Vector row = (Vector) data.elementAt(rows[0]);
                     row = (Vector) row.clone();                     
                     model.addRow(row);
                 }
            }
        });


        BtnDeleteRowPane1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  

                int row = TblFilePane1.getSelectedRow();

                if(row < 0 )
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Select a Row to Delete !");
                    return;
                }
                ((DefaultTableModel) TblFilePane1.getModel()).removeRow(row);

            }
        });

    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new UI();

    }
    //frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1000,820));
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The editor is still active when you click on the button. You need to stop editing before your remove the row.

You can add the following to your ActionListener:

```
if (TblFilePane1.isEditing())
    TblFilePane1.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
```

You should add it to both listeners. Or you may want to check out [Table Stop Editing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for a property you can set on the table to stop editing when the table loses focus.

Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and follow the [Java Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

Comment: Thanks ! @camickr and LuxxMiner it solved my Problem... the problem was the table cell was in editable state before deleting the row... so by using the above snippet it first stopped the cell editing before deleting. Thanks Again !